# Firefox getting wrone timezoneoffset, all the other browsers work fine

Tags: javascript

I need to get the timezone of the user so I'm trying to get it like this:

`var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); console.log(offset);`

this gives the right offset on any chromium based browser, but on firefox it gives 0.
I looked at my firefox settings and turned everything off that can affect the location. I checked my location from the browser it is correct but somehow this code gives the wrong timezone only in firefox.

I tried to get the timezone of the user, firefox gives the wrong timezone whatever I try.

Comment: What is your local offset? In other words, what *should* your result be? In Firefox right now I'm getting the correct offset (taking Daylight Savings/"Summer" Time into account).

Comment: My offset should be -180, which is what all the chromium based browsers log, but on firefox for some reason it logs 0. I'm really sure I turned off anything that can change the location on my browser.

Comment: Well apparently an implementation can return 0 when it has (or thinks it has) no time zone database available. I don't know how that would be happening.